# Removing intersection records doesn't work

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have an intersection table between two tables (this is a simplified scenario but still valid).

```
Answer -< AnswerTopic >- Topic
```

I wish to remove the intersection records for a particular answer, so used the following code...

```
answer.AnswerTopics.ToList().RemoveAll(at => at.AnswerID == answer.AnswerID);
```

...but found that the relevant rows in AnswerTopics simply don't go away.  It doesn't raise an error, they just stay there.  I got round the problem by using...

```
foreach (AnswerTopic answerTopic in answer.AnswerTopics.ToList())
    answer.AnswerTopics.Remove(answerTopic);
```

Nonetheless, this has been driving me nuts, I've tried about a dozen different ways of writing this and can't find the problem (I've probably been looking at it too long!).  Can someone please suggest why the first syntax doesn't remove the records.

Comment: It's simplified but essentially the same. The answer object is the owning object, not the dbcontext (so your link doesn't quite apply :( ). so I can't use RemoveRange(), It's necessary to use ToList() to allow access to RemoveAll() since AnswerTopics is ICollection.

Comment: `ToList` gives you `RemoveAll` but it also enumerates all `AnswerTopics` in EF collection returning you an ordinary list so you do not change the EF context in any way using that method.

Comment: Why do you filter it using at => at.AnswerID == answer.AnswerID? is there any answer.answerTopics which has AnswerID that is not equal to answer.AnswerID?

Comment: @Adil Mammadov Accidental hangover from one of the many, many iterations - RemoveAll needs a predicate and that one isn't invalid (which is not to say it is the best ;-P ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem here is you are creating new `List` by calling `ToList` and throwing it away after running your logic.

Probably what you need is

```
var list = answer.AnswerTopics.ToList();
list.RemoveAll(at => at.AnswerID == answer.AnswerID); 
answer.AnswerTopics =  list;
```

Comment: Ahhh, yup, knew I'd been looking at this too long, it's so damned obvious when you spell it out.  Thank you so much for returning my sanity to me!  Thanks to you too, Rafel.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have AnswerTopics Set and normally if you get **AnswerTopics** of one **answer**, there should not be any need to filter them by **AnswerID** assuming that AnserID is *primary key of Answer* and *foreign key to Answer from AnswerTopics*. Then you can use:

```
context.AnswerTopics.RemoveRange(
      answer.AnswerTopics.AsEnumerable());
```

Comment: Nice idea but, as I mentioned, I'm not using the dbcontext to access AnswerTopics but the answer object itself, so the RemoveRange method isn't available to me.  Nonetheless, a nice variation on the RemoveRange predicate that I hadn't explored so thanks for that - I'll have to have a play.